# i was trying to make a back button between two screens by toolbar but it shows error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

i am trying to make a map based app where i used a floating bar action button to change through one window to another i wanted another back button so i used toolbar which i mentioned in my xml activity by id toolbar_add_place  but it shows error here i have pasted screenshots you can see it can help  me thankyou[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIxjq.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATtGr.png)

Comment: Try using view binding to access the views

Comment: As @hasan_shaikh said, you'll want to use view binding or data binding if you want to easily get a reference to a view. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding. I prefer data binding as it gives you a way to directly bind some data to the layout

Answer (score 0):

```
class AddHappyPlacesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_happy_places)
        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_add_place)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener { 
            onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.happyplacess/com.example.happyplacess.AddHappyPlacesActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.   it is showing this error after running

Comment: change in your res/values/themes.xml (default + night)
 `<style name="Theme.HappyPlacess" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">`
to `<style name="Theme.HappyPlacess" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">`

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.happyplacess/com.example.happyplacess.AddHappyPlacesActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead. now it shows this error